# Creating an if statement for whether or not an if statement should be used?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm creating a site that has a status bar that updates its innerHTML depending on what is mouseovered by the user. The function that does this has a bunch of if statements in it but if the if statement finds that the conditions don't exist it throws alot of errors. For example:  I have an if statement that checks what the id is of the element 3 parent elements above a child element like this: `if( element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id == 'body' )`. But because i'm using one function this if statement throws the error **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null'** when the element doesnt meet that condition. My question: Is there a way to first check if the if statement is even going to work before i use it? This might sound dumb but It seems thats the only way to avoid the errors unless I use multiple functions - which I don't want. My code is below and heres a JS BIN of a very simplified version of my program: http://jsbin.com/hefotifopo/1/edit ( open the console to see my errors ).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header id = "header" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">
            <p>Header</p>
        </header>

        <section id = "body">
            <div id = "area1">
                <div>
                    <p id = "p1" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">
                        paragraph
                    </p>
                    <p id = "p2" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">
                        paragraph
                    </p>
                    <p id = "p3" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">
                        paragraph
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer><p id = "statusBar">Status Bar</p></footer>

        <script>
            document.body.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function( element ){
                statusSet( element.target );
            });

            function statusSet( element ){
                var elementId = element.id;
                var elementInner = element.innerHTML;

                if( elementId == 'body' || elementId == 'statusBar'  ){
                    document.getElementById( 'statusBar' )
                    .innerHTML = 'hovering over body';
                }
                else if( element.parentElement.parentElement
                .parentElement.id == 'body' ){
                    document.getElementById( 'statusBar' )
                    .innerHTML = 'hovering over paragraphs';
                }
                else if( element.id == 'header' ){
                    document.getElementById( 'statusBar' )
                    .innerHTML = 'hovering over header';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem as described can be solved easily, however I strongly recommend rethinking what you are doing, going through a chain of parent elements seems like a bad idea. By the way you can simply check `if (element.parentNode)`, this will be false if parentNode does not exist

Comment: One of the reasons why I'm checking for all these specific conditions in my function is because I was trying to use one universal function to accomplish the status bar changes and not all of my divs even have IDs, so I can't think of a better way? I am newb btw.

Comment: This is no way more general solution than using IDs, but it is definitely worse. IDs are there for programming, use them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check each reference:

```
else if (element.parentElement && element.parentElement.parentElement && element.parentElement.parentElement && element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id == "body")
```

It would really be better to work out a less fragile way of determining what's going on, for example by giving elements classes to distinguish their differing natures. Relying on the document structure like that means that you'll have to update your JavaScript if you make minor changes to the document.